# Does program really created the inner object each time?

Tags: python, python-3.x, coding-style

why i ask this question because i always worried about code like this style

```
def callsomething(x):
    if x in (3,4,5,6):
        #do something
```

if the function callsomething was called frequently ,did the (3,4,5,6) waste too much space and time?in some language like C, it might be putted into data segment like constant,but in python,i don't know how it works,so i tended to write code like this

```
checktypes = (3,4,5,6)#cache it
def callsomething(x):
    global checktypes
    if x in checktypes:
        #do something
```

but after test i found this way make program slower, in more complicated case, the code would be like this:

```
types = (3,4,5,6)
def callsomething(x):
    global types
    for t in types:
        t += x
        #do something
```

still slower than this

```
def callsomething(x):
    for t in (3+x,4+x,5+x,6+x):
        #do something
```

in this case, the program must create (3+x,4+x,5+x,6+x),right?but it still faster than the first version,not head too much though.

i know the global var access in python would slow down program but how dose it compare to creating an struct?

Comment: How are you testing this?

Comment: "how dose it compare to..." - no one knows your application better than you.  You should capitalize on [python profiling tools](http://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html) to find out how to best solve your problem.

Comment: well,in my project,i call it thousands times put different x and y,and measure the time.the second version one are always faster than the first one like 4% percent

Comment: @user2003548: The second one is 15% slower than the first for me.

Comment: maybe the answer told the difference , i didn't use python version lower than 3.3,so i added python-3.x tag

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't worry, it's stored as a constant (which explains why it's faster than you expected)

```
>>> def callsomething(x):
...     if x in (3,4,5,6): pass
... 
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(callsomething)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              3 LOAD_CONST               5 ((3, 4, 5, 6))
              6 COMPARE_OP               6 (in)
              9 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       15
             12 JUMP_FORWARD             0 (to 15)
        >>   15 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             18 RETURN_VALUE
```

Looking up `x` in a `set` should be faster, right? But Uh Oh...

```
>>> def callsomething(x):
...     if x in {3,4,5,6}: pass
... 
>>> dis.dis(callsomething)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 (3)
              6 LOAD_CONST               2 (4)
              9 LOAD_CONST               3 (5)
             12 LOAD_CONST               4 (6)
             15 BUILD_SET                4
             18 COMPARE_OP               6 (in)
             21 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       27
             24 JUMP_FORWARD             0 (to 27)
        >>   27 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             30 RETURN_VALUE
```

set is mutable, so Python hasn't made this optimization until recently. Python3.3 sees that it's safe to make this into a frozenset

```
Python 3.3.0 (default, Sep 29 2012, 17:17:45) 
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> def callsomething(x):
...     if x in {3,4,5,6}: pass
... 
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(callsomething)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (x) 
              3 LOAD_CONST               5 (frozenset({3, 4, 5, 6})) 
              6 COMPARE_OP               6 (in) 
              9 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       15 
             12 JUMP_FORWARD             0 (to 15) 
        >>   15 LOAD_CONST               0 (None) 
             18 RETURN_VALUE         
>>>
```

Comment: Pre python 3, would you be able to do like this: `if x in frozenset({3,4,5,6}):` and get the same optimization?

Comment: @Patashu, no. If you look at the disassembly, you'll notice that there is a `LOAD_GLOBAL` of `frozenset`, the `set` is still constructed again and then passed to `frozenset`.

Comment: @Patashu Python can't make that optimization because it's conceivable that you'd reassign the name `frozenset` to something else.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to do a hack so that you can get constants for things beyond tuples, you could do something gross like

```
def foo(x, dont_use_this=frozenset([1,2,3])):
    if x in dont_use_this:
        # do something
    return x
```

But don't do that.